# Xamarin Google play publish

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-play

In recent update Xamarin made it possible to publish android apps straight to the Google play (before you had to generate apk and upload it manually). [More info](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_3_-_publishing_an_application_on_google_play/)

[image]

These are my version numbers. I was at version 10437 when the update came, I made some changes and raised version number to 10438 and tried the new way of publishing. What happened is that my version number became 141510 for some reason and when I tried to do it again it became 207046. After that I set the number to 320000 and started uploading manully again.

I suspect that the reason for this is that I had  Multiple supported architectures and xamarin was uploading multiple apks and I was getting some errors about that. Since then I changed supported architectures to armeabi-v7a only.

Question is:

Can I somehow tell google to forget about these screwed up numbers so I can continue with my 10438 (it won't let me now, I get an error that version number must be bigger then the last one)? Also all versions after 10437 are private and this is the current version on beta (image is from beta channel).

Also do I lose mobile devices if I set my supported architecture as armeabi-v7a only?

Comment: Did you use the "Automating APK Creation With Rake" ? if yes please check the rakefile, if it overwrite your version code.

Comment: @MikeMa no Rake, just normal right-click > archive > distribute

Answer (score 0):

#### `versionCode` vs. `versionName`:

The `versionCode` is not shown to the user:

> An integer used as an internal version number. This number is used only to determine whether one version is more recent than another, with higher numbers indicating more recent versions. This is not the version number shown to users

Ref: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html

#### ABI Architecture:

Google does not breakdown the CPU Information/ABI Architectures in a Dashboard like they do for API level or screen resolution. You can get a device breakdown for your app install:

Ref: https://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/developer-console.html#app-stats

Assuming your app is not dependent on a 3rd-party NDK library that only supports a subset of all the ABIs, there is no *general* reason not to support multi-ABIs as you are just pre-limiting your applications available user-based.

#### Current API and Screen Sizes and Densities Distributions:

Ref: https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Comment: 1. I understand the difference, my question was can I revert the versionCode to 10437 and continue from there.

Comment: 2. Is there a list of CPU/ABI distribution anywhere?