# Android xamarin apk

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-play

[image]

When using xamarin archive to create apks locally I get 4 apks but I only uploaded the first one to play store. Is the first one bundle of the next 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this link：
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/cpu_architectures/

The first one **Mobile.apk** is to target multiple CPU architectures, you can select more than one ABI (at the expense of larger APK file size).

the next three apk is generate by using the Generate one package (.apk) per selected ABI option (described in Set Packaging Properties) to create a separate APK for each supported architecture.

So the **Mobile.apk** support multiple CPU architectures.
The next three support single  CPU architectures.

Comment: Is this a good practice? Because when I try to use automatic deploy from visual studio to google play with multiple apks strange things happen. Version code gets some random value and publish fails. if I just publish bundled version it works. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40807602/xamarin-google-play-publish/40808871#40808871

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have enabled create one APK per architecture/abi

You can disable it in your project properties to get a single APK instead. Here is more details on the subject https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/build-abi-specific-apks/

Answer (score 0):

You've created an APK for each architecture, best to check in projects -> your solution -> build and then un-tick "generate one APK per selected ABI.